# Opencart Ajax load on Product Filters

Tags: opencart

Currently I have following JavaScript in my filter.tpl file. This has hidden the refined search button and filters product on checkbox click. But It loads the whole page on a check box click. I want to implement AJAX loader so that only the page loads partially.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button-filter').hide();

        $('input[name^=\'filter\']').on('change', function() {
           filter = [];

            $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
               filter.push(this.value);
        });

        location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
     });
});
//--></script>
```